# Why i can not handle the store procedure return value is c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new in c#,and want to write simple application work with sql server store procedure,in the sql server write this store procedure:

```
USE [mammutRecruitment]
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FirstStep]
    @Name nvarchar(max),@Family nvarchar(max),@FatherName nvarchar(max),@BirthCertificate bigint,@PlaceOfBirth nvarchar(max),@BirthDate datetime,
    @NationalCode bigint,@Religion nvarchar(max),@faith nvarchar(max),@Nationality nvarchar(max),@BloodGroup nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MYID bigint
    insert into [dbo].[UserMainSpecifications] values(@Name,@Family,@FatherName,@BirthCertificate,@PlaceOfBirth,1,@BirthDate,@NationalCode,
    @Religion,@faith,@Nationality,@BloodGroup,12,'123','123',1,2015-1-1,'12','123','1234',1)

      select @MYID=[UserID] from [mammutRecruitment].[dbo].[UserMainSpecifications]
        where [NationalCode]=@NationalCode
        select @MYID as myID

END
```

and in c# write this code for call that:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mammutRecruitment;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FirstStep", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.Name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Family", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.Family;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FatherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.FatherName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthCertificate", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value =Convert.ToInt64(m.BirthCertificate);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlaceOfBirth", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.PlaceOfBirth;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NationalCode", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value =Convert.ToInt64(m.NationalCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Religion", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.Religion;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@faith", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.faith;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.Nationality;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BloodGroup", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m.BloodGroup;
                    SqlParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@myID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var retunvalue = cmd.Parameters["@myID"].Value;
```

but in the this line i get zero value always:

```
var retunvalue = cmd.Parameters["@myID"].Value;
```

What happen?How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: You aren't returning the value, you're just selecting it.  Either change your proc to be `RETURN @MyID` or change the code to `var returnvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: You add the parameter in C# code but you haven't that parameter between the input arguments of the stored procedure.

Comment: either use ExecuteScalar to get the single value returned by the query, or make the parameter an output parameter, and get its value that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is executing your query and not returning a value.

You could start by looking into using this instead:

```
 cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Or if you want the value of the first field of the first row, you could use this:

```
var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Which will give you an object that you can then convert or cast into the appropriate type for your method.

Answer (score 1):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

I believe you want the second method

Answer (score 0):

You need to include @myID as an output parameter in your stored procedure definition:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FirstStep]
    @Name nvarchar(max),@Family nvarchar(max),@FatherName nvarchar(max),@BirthCertificate bigint,@PlaceOfBirth nvarchar(max),@BirthDate datetime,
    @NationalCode bigint,@Religion nvarchar(max),@faith nvarchar(max),@Nationality nvarchar(max),@BloodGroup nvarchar(max)
    , @myID bigint output
AS
```

And then remove the line

```
DECLARE @MYID bigint
```

You also need to add the parameter to cmd in your c# code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(retval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need change that statement:

`retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;`

to

`retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`

because ExecuteNonQuery return:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.
>   Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data.

End include your parameter to procedure definition:
 `@myID BIGINT OUTPUT`

```
USE [mammutRecruitment] 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Firststep] @Name             NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @Family           NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @FatherName       NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @BirthCertificate BIGINT, 
                              @PlaceOfBirth     NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @BirthDate        DATETIME, 
                              @NationalCode     BIGINT, 
                              @Religion         NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @faith            NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @Nationality      NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @BloodGroup       NVARCHAR(max), 
                              @myID             BIGINT output 
AS 
  BEGIN 

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[usermainspecifications] 
  VALUES     (@Name, 
              @Family, 
              @FatherName, 
              @BirthCertificate, 
              @PlaceOfBirth, 
              1, 
              @BirthDate, 
              @NationalCode, 
              @Religion, 
              @faith, 
              @Nationality, 
              @BloodGroup, 
              12, 
              '123', 
              '123', 
              1, 
              2015 - 1 - 1, 
              '12', 
              '123', 
              '1234', 
              1) 

  SELECT @myID = [userid] 
  FROM   [mammutRecruitment].[dbo].[usermainspecifications] 
  WHERE  [nationalcode] = @NationalCode 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

you need define @MYID as output parameter.

```
  USE [mammutRecruitment]
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FirstStep]
        @MYID bigint output,@Name nvarchar(max),@Family nvarchar(max),@FatherName nvarchar(max),@BirthCertificate bigint,@PlaceOfBirth nvarchar(max),@BirthDate datetime,
        @NationalCode bigint,@Religion nvarchar(max),@faith nvarchar(max),@Nationality nvarchar(max),@BloodGroup nvarchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN

        insert into [dbo].[UserMainSpecifications] values(@Name,@Family,@FatherName,@BirthCertificate,@PlaceOfBirth,1,@BirthDate,@NationalCode,
        @Religion,@faith,@Nationality,@BloodGroup,12,'123','123',1,2015-1-1,'12','123','1234',1)

          select @MYID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    END
```

and add your command

```
SqlParameter pOut = new SqlParameter("@MYID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
pOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pOut);
```

You can read the value now

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long newId = (long)pOut.Value;
```